# Defining minor-mode buffer-local variables

Tags: minor-mode, buffer-local

I want to do something  VERY simple. I want to create a minor mode, which when enabled sets a buffer-local variable (say `left-margin-width`, for instance) with a specific value.

I can do this:

```
(define-minor-mode margin-mode
  (setq left-margin-width 3))
```

Now, I want the variable to take back it's global value when `margin-mode` is disabled. To me this seems like a very natural use-case, but apparently I can't find a simple and easy way to do his yet! Once enabled, the variable retains it's value until the buffer is closed. Which is very undesirable.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Minor modes are toggles. Defining a minor mode also creates a variabel with the same name. This variable is toggled when enabling/disabling the minor mode.
So following code works:

```
(define-minor-mode margin-mode
  (if (not margin-mode)
      (setq left-margin-width 3)
    (setq left-margin-width (default-value 'left-margin-width))))
```

Elisp is a Lisp-n type language. This means there exist separate namespaces for function names and variable names. You can have a variable and a function with the same name. This is used here.

(instead of resetting the local variable with `(setq left-margin-width (default-value 'left-margin-width))` you could also use `(kill-local-variable 'left-margin-width)`.

---

To get more info on how to define minor modes, read the documentation. you can access the documentation with `C-h f define-minor-mode <RET>`

Comment: Thanks. I kinda knew this. I was wondering if it was workable without using an explicit condition check.

Comment: Also this wouldn't work with the margins cause apparently setting the variable isn't enough.

Comment: `C-h v left-margin-width` tells you that you have to call `set-window-buffer` to make changes to this variable take effect. But this was not what you asked about, so I expected, you already know this.

Comment: Have a look at public source code minor modes, most use a `if` or `when` or `unless` and the minor-mode variable to act according.

Answer (score 1):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `kill-local-variable` for reverting a buffer-local variable to the global state.

If you just set the buffer-local value to the variable's current default value, then it's still a buffer-local value (i.e. it won't reflect future changes to the default).